# Xcode IOS how to load data from plist in multiple views

Tags: ios, xcode, load, plist

Something killing me here, I have my app which creates and writes to a plist in the docs folder just fine, via one single view controller. My plist will hold different categories of grouped data. For exampl contact email addresses and contact mobile phone numbers.

Foe this I have an EmailViewController and an SmsViewController. Each write their respective arrays to the plist as emailarray and smsarray.

A third ViewControler should read data from both arrays and use it in the app. That is my problem. Using the exact same load method as the email and SMS viewcontrollers does not work.

In this case I have the same load method on each view controller. I feel that there has to be a far better way of so many views accessing the same plist. Should I be loading this from a special "data controller" or perhaps load in the app delegate.m ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? We can't help much without seeing exactly how you're loading and saving this plist file.

Answer (score 0):

So, let me get this straight.  You are loading/saving plist files to the Documents folder successfully in your EmailViewController and your SmsViewController, but you have one other view that it does not work for (using the same code)?  As Tim said, sample code would be helpful.

When using plists, I like to create a class that can act as a universal plist loader.  In your program, whenever you need a plist loaded, you can declare a new object instance of your plist loader class (plistLoader.m/h) then pass the name of a file that you want loaded and/or saved, and let it do all the work.  Doing this can definitely help you avoid duplicate code.